# How do I create a function or script in octave that returns a vector?

Tags: octave

I am trying to create a function that creates a vector and the returns it.

How can I do this? Various Octave tutorials only seem to show how to return multiple variables, but not a vector.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Store the vector, that you want to return, in one of those variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the Octave documentation on [Defining Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Defining-Functions.html).

The general syntax is:

```
function ret-var = name (arg-list)
  body
endfunction
```

A simple example would be:

```matlab
function v = funcThatReturnsAVector()
  v = zeros(5,1);
endfunction
```

Then save the above as a file and you're all set.